# AJAX use php variable returned to write if statement (Jquery Mobile/Ajax/Php)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a login script where the user will enter their username and password. This will be sent via ajax to a php script to check if the details are correct. If they are the user should then be able to select a site, which ive been trying to display like this `$('#logonContainer').load("login_DisplaySelectSite.php");`

My problem is that I cant figure out how to run this code if the session has started with a valid username. Heres my code so far, maybe someone can help me!

html/jquery mobile:

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <form id='login' onsubmit="return false;">      
                <div id='logonContainer' style="background-color: #F8F4FA; padding: 10px;  width:70%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:15%;">
                    <input type="text" name='user' id='user' placeholder='Username'>
                    <input type="password" name='password' id='password' placeholder='Password'>
                    <input type="submit" id="submitLogin" name="login" value="Login" class='ui-btn ui-btn-c ui-btn-inline' data-theme='c' data-transition='pop'>
                </div>
            </form>
    <div id="resultLog"></div>
</div>
```

ajax:

```
$(function userLogin() {

        $("#submitLogin").click(function() {
            var theUser = $.trim($("#user").val());
            var thePassword = $.trim($("#password").val());

            if(theUser.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "callajax.php",
                  data: ({usr: theUser, pwd: thePassword}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: onSuccess
                });
            }
        });

        $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
          $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
        });

        function onSuccess(data)
        {
            $("#resultLog").html(data);


        }
```

This next bit is not working at all!! This is where I'm trying to display a radio button list to replace the username and passowrd fields. After this I guess I will use a similar function to select the site, again, dependant on the session being active - once all these checks have been done the user should be sent to the home page

```
        if(onSuccess(data) == 1) 
        {
            $('#logonContainer').load("login_DisplaySelectSite.php");

        } else {

        }

    });
```

php:

```
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['usr']=="admin" && $_REQUEST['pwd']=="1234"){

    $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = "admin";
    $_SESSION['SESSIONID']='123456';

    echo "Login CORRECT WOOOOOOOO!! </br>" ;
    //print json_encode($_SESSION);
    print $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
    $loggedon=1;
    echo json_encode( $loggedon);

}
else{
    echo "Incorrect Login :(" ;
    $loggedon=0;
    echo  json_encode($loggedon);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In your AJAX function you're not passing anything to the `onSuccess()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I see `data` isn't defined yet? And you might want to add this line too: `data: $( "#login" ).serialize()` in `$.ajax();`

Comment: how should I define data? Sorry for my ignorance I'm a total ajax newbie!

Comment: Did you try to add the line `data: $( "#login" ).serialize()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the signature of the success event.
Just add the parameter to Success: 
**success: onSuccess(data)**
and try to check, it should work fine.

to check if the success, event is triggered its better to use some debugging tools or alerts/console messages/print to screen etc based on your development environment and IDE that you use, that will tell you if its working fine.

thanks.

Comment: this stopped the script from returning anything?!

Comment: if you are not getting any data/result that means you are not receiving any response from the server/requested page.
**if(onSuccess(data) == 1)** call will not work as it **onSuccess** is not a method, its an event.
 so if you want to execute any code based on the return/response you should write inside the **onSuccess** event/defination.

Comment: @Janey : if you want to use the response all over the page/js you should store it in var **eg: var _response;** and use this **_response** variable to verify or validate against any.
--Thanks.